# Can't log into Oracle DB 19c on command line - SQL Developer is fine

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I can't log into Oracle 19c DB on the command line. This is the error I get:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Nov 19 16:35:55 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:
```

If I check the status of the listener it looks like it's running to me (unless I'm mistaken):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> lsnrctl status LISTENER1

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 19-NOV-2021 16:37:29

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-0T5DL1G)(PORT=1555)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER1
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                19-NOV-2021 16:07:28
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 30 min. 10 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\Oracle_1\instantclient\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         D:\Oracle_1\app09\oracle\base\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-0T5DL1G\listener1\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-0T5DL1G)(PORT=1555)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1555ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-0T5DL1G)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=D:\ORACLE_1\APP09\ORACLE\BASE\admin\aws\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0.company.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "aws", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "5f0fbe5bc87148669145f9e2458c91b2.company.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "aws", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "aws.company.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "aws", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdb1.company.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "aws", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Yet, I can log in with SQL Developer and run queries:

[image]

If I try to start the service it says that it's already been started:

```
PS C:\Users\bluet> net start OracleServiceAWS
The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.
```

I'm really curious as to why I can't log in on the command line and in Oracle SQL developer it's fine! I'd like to correct this so I can log in again on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to specify the **container** you're connecting to. For example:

```
sqlplus sys/its_password@pdb as sysdba
                        ----
                        this is your pluggable database
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But I've never had to do that before. Only since the last reboot I've done. It's always worked as simply as `sqlplus / as sysdba` before that. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @bluethundr Which oracle process do you want sqlplus to connect to? sqlplus / as sysdba is an inter-process connection type. It does not use the networking stack. All you have to do is to provide the oracle process name. In your case it is going to be "set ORACLE_SID=aws"

Comment: Yes, I wanted to connect to the AWS database. After setting `set ORACLE_SID=aws` I was able to connect to the database with `sqlplus / as sysdba` without specifying the container again. Thanks!